# string.split for alternating characters in c#

Tags: c#, string, split

I know this is going to be an easy answer but I am new to C#. There is a lot of answers on for different types of splits, but I cannot find one for this problem. I am trying to split a string into two by alternating characters.

The example would be: `string example = "stackoverflow"` and the output would be `"sakvrlo"` and `"tcoefo"`.

If it is an odd number of characters it does not matter if the two new strings are of different lengths.

Thanks!

Comment: If this is homework it is appreciated if you mention that (or use the tag).

Comment: This is not my career and it is not homework. I am trying to teach myself to program for fun and literally have a c# for dummies book. For the love of all that is binary if it is that easy why didn't you just print the answer instead of telling me how dumb I am

Comment: No man, I'm not telling you you are dumb, I'm trying to tell you that you are smart and that you CAN solve this yourself. Seriously. Don't look at solutions below. Even if you are new, reading solutions isn't going to do anything for you. Solving it will teach you to think.

Comment: @miltonjbradley While it really **is** very easy for any programmer worth her salt, I don't think that was the purpose of Niko's comment. This was more on the lines: "don't quite so easily, you can do it yourself". And forcing yourself to go through the mental motions necessary to solve what is not necessarily an easy problem for a "civilian", is the only way you can teach yourself to "think like a programmer". In many ways, programming is more about how you think than how much you know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var a = new string(source.Where((c,i) => i % 2 == 0).ToArray());
var b = new string(source.Where((c,i) => i % 2 != 0).ToArray());
```

Comment: LINQ usually produces short and maintainable solutions to such things. Mastering it pays off all the time.

Comment: @usr: but LINQ doesn't always result in efficient solutions. E.g. this solution will loop over the string twice, whereas the other solutions will only loop once.

Comment: Yeah it is slow as a dog. But most of the time that does not matter much.

Comment: usr: I look up LINQ and I am going to learn how to use it but can you explain how I then reference the two separate strings? I don't understand where it stores the split. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Edit: In the variables a and b.

Comment: Usr: Thank-you for the help. It is so much easier for to have a working solution so I can then learn why it works. I appreciate it.

Comment: OH GOD NOT THE LINQ SOLUTION! At least go for the Tim Medora's one, its BETTER AND it demonstrates what should have been done. This one just demonstrates usr's proficiency with LINQ.

Comment: Niko, performance is not always most important. From your comments I can tell that you are not inexperienced. You must know this. Please revert your downvote, it is just a mean move of yours.

Comment: Okay, I reverted it, but this isn't about performance, OP stated that he was trying to learn. I do think your solution is cool, but you have to agree that it teaches him nothing. It's too soon to be going for LINQ if you can't think of atleast a dozen ways to split a string in two. (Sorry about the downvote, got carried away)

Comment: Niko, I think your point about exposure to LINQ being to early is correct. Although functional programming skills are quite useful. I really would have chosen this exact solution in production, except if there was a concrete reason to do it differently.

Answer (score 5):

```
StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();

string source = "some string to split";

// ALTERNATE: if you want an explicitly typed char[]
// char[] source = "some string to split".ToCharArray();

for( int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++ )
{
   if( i % 2 == 0 )
   {
        sb1.Append( source[i] );
   }
   else
   {
        sb2.Append( source[i] );
   } 
}
```

Notes:

- There is no BCL method that I am aware of that does this automatically (e.g. `string.SplitAlternating()`.
- Since the size of the string is known, the `StringBuilders` can be initialized with a fixed buffer size.
- LINQ solution (@usr's answer) is cleaner but slower (if it matters, which is probably rarely).
- If performance truly does matter, the fastest way is probably to obtain a pointer to the start of the original char array and iterate by incrementing two separate pointers created by two char arrays declared using `stacalloc`. Subsequently, those two char arrays can then be passed as an argument to string's constructor. Make sure to append null terminators.

Comment: @LB - if I want to help someone then that is my prerogative. Unless my answer is wrong it shouldn't be downvoted.

Comment: While I was writing the comment, I was pretty sure that it was an homework, and giving the complete answer wouldn't have helped him much.

Comment: How is giving solutions to trivial problems helping OP learn to program? I agree that it shouldn't be downvoted, but I also think that these answers shouldn't have been posted at all.

Comment: It's up to the OP how they want to learn. Maybe seeing an example **helps**. Some people learn that way. Maybe they are working on something far more complex and this question is a tiny part of the problem that that they just want to get past. Even a simple problem like this shows the use of efficient string building, the relationship between strings/char arrays, and the use of the remainder operator in c#.

Comment: Well to be perfectly honest, your solution did make me realize I'm not using StringBuilder as often as I should. Also, you could index through string, no need to turn it into char array. But I still think this isn't helping OP :)

Comment: @NikoDrašković - fair enough. And yes, I realized that I could just treat the string as a char[] too. That's why I like solving simple little problems. It's a challenge when you have only 60 seconds to think about the answer and the whole SO community will examine it. I also did list the fastest method I have found for alternating string building (char pointers).

Comment: I see a nice Linq and StringBuilder solution, both of which the OP will indirectly learn about their existence and an example of their applications.